# Why does python class definition print statements not in functions?

Tags: python

As you may have gathered I am brand new to Python and programming in general and I am trying to understand the terminology.  All discussions of class have described it as a blueprint that is not created until it is called or defined.  Yet the statement is printed right away with the code:

```
    class Test():
        print "this is a test"
    >>>>this is a test
```

When based on the definition of a class I would not expect it to be printed until the class is called, like with a function:

```
    a = Test()
    >>>
    (here I would expect to see >>>this is a test)
```

I am thinking it has something to do with the creation of namespaces as described in python docs but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Because anything in the class definition gets run when the class is defined. If you want it to run when an instance of the class is created, it needs to be in `__init__`.

Comment: Thank you the clarification of defined and created helps a lot and further clarifies the difference between a class and a function.  I will continue to play....